# How to convert columns to rows in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am performing data QA testing.

I have this query to establish any errors between the source table and the destination table.

```
select 
count(case when coalesce(x.col1,1) = coalesce(y.col1,1) then null else 1 end) as cnt_col1,
count(case when coalesce(x.col2,"1") = coalesce(y.col2,"1") then null else 1 end) as cnt_col2
from
`DatasetA.Table` x
OUTER JOIN
`DatasetB.Table` y
on x.col1 = y.col1
```

The output of this query is like this:

```
col1, col2
null, null
null, null
1, null
null, 1
```

I have 200 tables that I need to perform this test on, and the number of `cols` are dynamic.  the table above only has two columns, some have 50.

I have the queries for the tables already, but I need to conform the output of all of the tests into a single output.  My plan is to conform each query into a unified output and join them together using a `UNION ALL`.

The output set should say:

```
COLUMN, COUNT_OF_ERRORS
cnt_col1, 1
cnt_col2, 1
...
cnt_col15, 0
```

My question is this.
How do I reverse pivot this so I can achieve the output I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: `How do I reverse pivot this so I can achieve the output I'm looking for.` - can yo visualize this by showing example of expected output here!

Comment: I did...it's the third code block.

Comment: i see now - it was not clear for me

Comment: can you clarify how you count errors  - based on your example i would say col1 has 1 error and col2 has 1 error but in final output you show 0 for both?

Comment: so, the way it is now, is that the column name of each column is `cnt_<<col>>`.  there will be only one record, with the fields of that record  having a number that represent the columns errors.  I need that output turned sideways so the first column is the label `cnt_<<col>>` and the second column be the count.

Comment: that's clear  - but read my question-in-comment again :o)

Comment: ok.  trying again.  the way it works, is the SELECT reads both tables, and does a join against them by primary key.  The count(col1 compare) does a compare against col1 on table a and col1 on table b.  if they match then null, if they don't then 1.  the count() part adds all the 1's for a final output.

Comment: which means that based on your example (block 2) in your expected output (block 3) count for cnt_col1 should be 1 and for cnt_col2 should be 1 - even though you might think it is not important for your question  - but it is - IMPORTANT - to present all clear and clean. :o) so we can help effectivelly

Comment: ok.  I'll update block three.  you are correct.

Comment: changed. appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I reverse pivot this so I can achieve the output I'm looking for.

Assuming you have table `data`

```
col1    col2    col3
----    ----    ----     
null    null    null     
null    null    1    
null    1       1    
1       null    1    
1       null    1    
1       null    1
```

And you need reverse pivot it to

```
column      count_of_errors  
--------    ---------------
cnt_col1    3    
cnt_col2    1    
cnt_col3    5
```

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and does exactly this

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `data` AS (
  SELECT NULL AS col1, NULL AS col2, NULL AS col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, 1
)
SELECT r.* FROM (
  SELECT 
    [
    STRUCT<column STRING, count_of_errors INT64>
      ('cnt_col1', SUM(col1)),
      ('cnt_col2', SUM(col2)),
      ('cnt_col3', SUM(col3))
    ] AS row
  FROM `data`
), UNNEST(row) AS r
```

It is simple enough and friendly for adjusting to any number of columns you potentially have in your initial `data` table  - you just need to add respective number of `('cnt_colN', SUM(colN)),` - which can be done manually or you can just write simple script to generate those lines (or whole query)

Comment: i am glad it helped! love BigQuery and also love SO as it gives opportunity to pass/share knowledge and help people :o)

Comment: How to do it dynamically? When the number of columns are many

Answer (score 1):

About "comparing 2 tables" in Big Data, I don't think that doing some Joins is the best approach, because Joins are quite slow in general and then you have to handle the case of "outer" joins rows.

I worked on this topic years ago (https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/1283/hive-script-to-validate-tables-compare-one-with-an.html) and I am now trying to backport this knowledge to compare Hive tables with BigQuery tables.

One of my main idea is to use some checksums to be sure that a table is fully identical to the other one.
Here is a "basic example":

```
with one_string as(
select concat( sessionid ,'|',referrercode ,'|',purchaseid ,'|',customerid ,'|', cast(bouncerateind as string),'|', cast( productpagevisit as string),'|', cast( itemordervalue as string),'|', cast( purchaseinsession as string),'|', cast( hit_time_gmt as string),'|',datedir ,'|',productcategory ,'|',post_cookies) as bigstring from bidwh2.omniture_2017_03_24_v2
),
shas as(
   select TO_BASE64( sha1( bigstring)) as sha from one_string
),
shas_prefix as(
   select substr( sha, 0 , 1) as prefix, sha from shas
),
shas_ordered as(
    select prefix, sha from shas_prefix order by sha
 ),
results_prefix as(
    select concat( prefix, ' ', TO_BASE64( sha1( STRING_AGG( sha, '|')))) as res from shas_ordered group by prefix
),
results_ordered as(
    select 1 as myall, res from results_prefix order by res
)
select SHA1( STRING_AGG( res, '|')) as sha from results_ordered group by myall;
```

So you do that on each of the 2 tables, and compare the 2 checksums numbers.

Final idea is to have an Python script (not finished yet, I hope my company allows me to opensource when finished) that would do the following:

1. count the rows for some "buckets" (groups of rows that whose column with a good distribution has the same checksum modulo a big number) and compare the results (because there is no need to checksum the whole table if the number of rows does not match).
2. visually shows the differences if count does not match
3. use the bucket/rows technique + some other "buckets/columns" to do some checksums in a similar way as shown in above example. And compare all those checksums together.
4. visually shows the differences if checksums do not match

**Edit on 03/11/2017**: script is finished and can be found at: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq

Comment: Sourygna, this is a brilliant strategy, and I'd like to see how you take it through fruition when you employ your python code.  However, my people said that I have to identify those columns that do  not match to determine if we have a transformation failure.  For row checks, this sounds strong.  Thank you fro the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, the idea of the point 3) is to be able to see the both the rows AND the columns that don't match. I divide into "buckets of columns" in order to reduce the quantity of intermediate results (checksums). That also means that when I show the differences in point 4), I'll be able to show to the final user only some groups of columns that fail (a group would be made of about 5 columns).
Let's see if I can finish soon in the next few days and if I can show you some results.

Comment: Here is the project of the Python script I mentioned before:

https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq