# Convert wide to log in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, aggregate-functions

I am working with a wide table that I want to pivot to a tall output in BigQuery. This data comes from a COVID dataset, but I have adjusted the number of cases from 9 digits to 1-2 for the code below. The numbers in the date column (eg. `_8_31_21`) are the cumulative number of cases within that country on that date, which is either the end of the month or the last date data was collected.

```
country    _8_31_21       _9_30_21       _10_31_21      _11_16_21
usa        1              3              5              9
germany    1              2              4              12
russia     1              2              3              6
uk         2              3              6              10
spain      0              2              3              8
portugal   1              2              5              16
```

This is my current query to find the total worldwide number of cases per month.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(_8_31_21) AS august_2021_cases,
  SUM(_9_30_21) AS september_2021_cases,
  SUM(_10_31_21) AS october_2021_cases,
  SUM(_11_16_21) AS november_2021_cases
FROM
  cases.table
```

The full queried table has 23 columns, but as an example, here is what I get when I submit the query above.

```
august_2021_cases   september_2021_cases    october_2021_cases     november_2021_cases
6                   14                      26                     61
```

What is the best option to get the desired output below?

```
month_year              cases

august_2021_cases       6
september_2021_cases    14
october_2021_cases      26
november_2021_cases     61
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looking into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222920/how-to-conform-columns-to-rows-in-google-big-query , Mikhail Berlyant has answered a similar question

Comment: Yes, thank you @Avi